# Smooth scroll having trouble in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im working on a website that has a sticky nav and a smooth scroll anchor in firefox and ie everything works fine. But in chrome and Safari the smooth scroll will not work.

To get the smooth scroll to work I removed the overflow styling from the html tag:

```
html, body{  
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

and the smooth scroll works but then the sticky nav stopped working.
I might have to redo the sticky nav to make this all work but if there a simple solution I would love to here it.

Comment: In your global js I would check to see if there is a target after line 123 with something like if (target) { smoothScroll(target); }.  I don't know if this will help with your problem but will prevent an error on page load.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that error itsa not what is causing the problem but I will try what you suggest to get rid of that error.

Comment: I figured it out actually I had to change the way the sticky navigation was being incorporated so it would use different styles and then I was able to remove the overflow hidden and overflow-y auto from the body and apply it only to the html.